# what is the use of min_informtaive_str in theano

Tags: theano

What is the use of `min_informtaive_str`? Some examples would help me to understand. I tried the theano documentation at http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/theano.pdf. But I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation is missing from the PDF (it does get out of date) then you can find the details in the source code. Here, for example, is [the source code for `min_informative_str`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/printing.py#L1224). It says:

```
Returns a string specifying to the user what obj is
The string will print out as much of the graph as is needed
for the whole thing to be specified in terms only of constants
or named variables.


Parameters
----------
obj: the name to convert to a string
indent_level: the number of tabs the tree should start printing at
              (nested levels of the tree will get more tabs)
_prev_obs: should only be used by min_informative_str
                a dictionary mapping previously converted
                objects to short tags


Basic design philosophy
-----------------------

The idea behind this function is that it can be used as parts of
command line tools for debugging or for error messages. The
information displayed is intended to be concise and easily read by
a human. In particular, it is intended to be informative when
working with large graphs composed of subgraphs from several
different people's code, as in pylearn2.

Stopping expanding subtrees when named variables are encountered
makes it easier to understand what is happening when a graph
formed by composing several different graphs made by code written
by different authors has a bug.

An example output is:

A. Elemwise{add_no_inplace}
    B. log_likelihood_v_given_h
    C. log_likelihood_h


If the user is told they have a problem computing this value, it's
obvious that either log_likelihood_h or log_likelihood_v_given_h
has the wrong dimensionality. The variable's str object would only
tell you that there was a problem with an
Elemwise{add_no_inplace}. Since there are many such ops in a
typical graph, such an error message is considerably less
informative. Error messages based on this function should convey
much more information about the location in the graph of the error
while remaining succint.

One final note: the use of capital letters to uniquely identify
nodes within the graph is motivated by legibility. I do not use
numbers or lower case letters since these are pretty common as
parts of names of ops, etc. I also don't use the object's id like
in debugprint because it gives such a long string that takes time
to visually diff.
```